# select from subquery with union and paginate in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have a MySql script that works perfectly fine when run in PHP native.

```
SELECT * FROM (
(SELECT * FROM news WHERE ctg = 'Promotion' and active = '1' ORDER BY id)
  UNION ALL
(SELECT * FROM news WHERE ctg ='Info' ORDER BY id)    
) AS hasil
ORDER BY id DESC
```

Currently I'm learning how to do it in laravel eloquent way. Here is the script:

```
$promo  = DB::select("SELECT * FROM (
(SELECT * FROM news WHERE ctg = 'Promotion' and active = '1' ORDER BY id)
  UNION ALL
(SELECT * FROM news WHERE ctg ='Info' ORDER BY id)
) AS hasil
ORDER BY id DESC ");
return view('news', ['promo' => $promo]);
```

The script above is working perfectly too unless it can't automatically parsing a pagination.

so how I should done it to get the result right and it could parsing a pagination too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont know why you are using `Union` in this case, the results seems the same as an `OR` condition, try this with the `News` model

```
$promo = News::where(function($query){
        $query->where('ctg', '=', 'Promotion')
            ->where('active', '=', '1');
    })
    ->orWhere('ctg', '=', 'info')
    ->orderBy('id', 'DESC')
    ->paginate(10);
return view('news', ['promo' => $promo]);
```

Comment: As a model yes, you can change it with `\DB::table('news')->where(...` if you dont have a model for `News`

Comment: thanks man , it works perfectly . don't know the solution is simpler than i thought . cheers